# SQL to get user's first picture and most common item

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join

I have 3 tables:

**user**

- id_user
- name

**user_picture**

- id_picture
- id_user
- filename
- ord (order of pictures)

**user_sticker**

- id_sticker
- id_user_from
- id_user_to

This is my current SQL call.

```
SELECT
    u.id_user,
    u.name,
    p.filename,
    s.id_sticker,
    FROM user AS u
    LEFT JOIN user_picture AS p ON p.id_user = u.id_user
    LEFT JOIN user_sticker AS s ON s.id_user_to = u.id_user
WHERE u.id_user = 1
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_sticker AS s2 WHERE s2.id_user_to = u.id_user AND s2.id_sticker = s.id_sticker)
```

I need to get a specific user's most common received sticker and also the user's first available picture (the one that has ord = 1). A user can have many stickers (and repeated stickers as well) and also many pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the sql:

```
select
    u.id_user,
    u.name,
    (select p.filename from user_picture as p where p.id_user=u.id_user and ord=1) as userpicture,
    (select max(s.id_sticker) from user_sticker as s where s.id_user_to=u.id_user) as userstickerid
from user as u
where u.id_user = $$$$
```

Comment: Just one question about this solution, what if I should also get a second column in the user picture call? Lets say: filename, caption

Comment: then you need to change it to join, like `select
    u.id_user,
    u.name,
p.filename, p.caption,
    (select max(s.id_sticker) from user_sticker as s where s.id_user_to=u.id_user) as userstickerid
from user as u left outer join user_picture as p on (p.id_user=u.id_user and p.ord=1)
where u.id_user = $$$$`

Comment: Thanks! In terms of benchmarking tests, which performs better? (in case the caption is not needed)

Comment: if you have indexes on `(user.id_user)` - suppose it is primary key, and add unique index to `(user_pictures.id_user, user_pictures.ord)` - then both should have same performance, but try with `explain extended`